# UPDATE not updating via script yet variables exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have the following code which should result in an UPDATE occuring yet I see no change on the table row. Any clues as to why? Below the code I list what I have tried. I've stared at this code for hours!

```
if (in_array( $topicid , $allowed )) { 

        $query = $db->query("SELECT lastpost FROM table_topics WHERE forumid=$forumid AND topicid=$topicid");
        $thelpost = $db->fetch_array($query);
        $db->free_result($query);

    $lastpost = explode("|", $thelpost['lastpost']);
        $initialtime = $lastpost[2];
        $timerightnow = time();
    $db->query("UPDATE table_topics SET lastpost='$timerightnow|$loginname|$initialtime' WHERE topicid=$topicid AND forumid=$forumid");

}
```

Tried printing the query:

```
$query = $db->query("UPDATE table_topics SET lastpost='$timerightnow|$loginname|$initialtime' WHERE topicid=$topicid AND forumid=$forumid");
print $query;
```

which resulted in output of 1 which I figure is true.

Tried echoing out variables and they all have the expected output. $loginname and other variables were set in preceeding code not shown.

Tried running the UPDATE manually through phpmyadmin with preset variables. Worked.

Yes, CSV delimiting is bad. It's a legacy app that needs overhauling in the long term.

Comment: Also have tried a simple update to a different table and that worked, so there is something odd on
    $db->query("UPDATE table_topics SET lastpost='$timerightnow|$loginname|$initialtime' WHERE topicid=$topicid AND forumid=$forumid");

Comment: Tried an exit() immediately after the UPDATE and it updated. Must be hitting another area of the script that updates again with the original data!